# Working with cyrillic through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, locale, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have windows 10 with WSL as my host machine and arch linux guest, I also have two scripts.
Fist, on host windows machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat clip | /mnt/c/Window/System32/clip.exe
```

Second, on remote guest machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

scp /home/sandric/clip host:clip
ssh host "./hclip.sh"
```

As you can see, file clip is populated with some text on remote machine, then it gets sent via scp to host machine, and in the end its content is put into windows clipboard. Everything work great, untill this file has cyrillic contents, like "тест". If I invoke `./hclip.sh` from remote machine - clipboard gets populated with gyberrish "╤é╨╡╤ü╤é", but strangely enough, if instead I run script straight, not from ssh session - I get cyrillic text as expected.

In other words, doing this from windows host machine: `./hclip.sh` (which contents is `cat clip | /mnt/c/Window/System32/clip.exe`) with "тест" I get the same "тест" in clipboard. But if instead I login into guest linux first, and then run "ssh './hclip.sh'" with the same "тест" in clip file - I get gyberrish.

I think I missing some locale setting in ssh configuration, which is it? Where should I place it, in /etc/ssh/config, or local .ssh/config?

UPDATE

After some testing, I found out that its actually `ControlPersist` ssh setting that is causing incorrect encoding for some reason. Here's my config for guest ssh:

```
host host
    HostName 10.0.2.2
    User sandric
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath /tmp/ssh-host
    ControlPersist yes #Causing trouble
```

If I comment last line - all working perfect, the thing is that its long - I dont want to close tunnel and open new connection any time I want to write smth into clipboard.

Comment: You're saying that the same `clip` file gets copied to the clipboard differently depending on whether the command is executed in a local terminal vs a ssh login on the same machine? Can you post `locale` output when logged in via ssh, and separately when logged in locally?

Comment: @thatotherguy I dont see point of it - as I said, even is file is not changed, doing "./hclip.sh" without ssh puts into clipboard as needed, if I then ssh guest and run "ssh host './hclip.sh'" - I get nonsense, file is not changed. Locales are - remote: "sandric@sandric-arch ~> ssh host "locale"
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
"

Comment: to upper comment - locale locally:
"LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="

Yes, I can see now that "C.UTF-8" is missing. Where should I add this locale change?

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Locally, the encoding is correctly set to UTF-8 whereas via SSH, it's incorrectly set to POSIX (7-bit ascii or iso-8859-1 depending on who you ask). In this case, it hinges on the variable `LANG`. It's probably being inherited via SSH, so fix it on your remote terminal, whatever that happens to be. If you don't know/care, you can kludge it with `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ./hclip.sh`

Comment: @thatotherguy Hmm, I tried to set in bash_profile and profile, and played a bit trying this "ssh host 'LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ./hclip.sh'" and "export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 && ./hclip.sh" - but with no luck for some reason, but "LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 locale" shows me that utf-8 is set..

Comment: If you add `locale` to your `hclip.sh`, does it show the same output for both the working and the failing invocation?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I'm doing all of it in wsltty.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, if I call `ssh host "LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ./hclip.exe"` with locale command before copy to clipboard call - I see C.UTF-8 in LC variables. But still get gybberish for some reason.

Comment: LC_ALL of the canonical override variable. You could try it with LANG instead in case WSL does it differently

Comment: @thatotherguy I tried both

Comment: @thatotherguy I found that its has something to do with `ControlPersist ` directive in ssh config, I updated question if you interested

Comment: Fascinating, thanks for the update. It looks fine from a Unix point of view, so I'm guessing it's due to WSL leaking a mismatch between Linux and Windows locale handling.